# Policy on low-quality questions

Tags: discussion, review

I recently got access to the "Low quality posts" review part. In the queue there was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249095/prove-that-ca-b-is-complete-with-the-max-norm), one of these obvious [homework] questions. It was flagged as "low quality" because of its length and content, which I can agree on.

I tried to find an option how to deal with it. It certainly did not "Look good", I could not "Edit" it, to improve it, the options for "Recommend close" did not fit either. What to do in such a situation? I assume this happens more often. I didn't do anything and @martini chose "Looks good" then.

To me [this meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5045/reviewing-low-quality-posts-how-to-handle-downvoted-answers) on how to handle down-voted answers with "low quality" seems related but not quite the same.

Comment: That user asked an overall $18$ questions with average score $-1.\dot8$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Looks good" in the low-quality queue effectively means "does not need to be deleted", and should be used for all posts that you're sure are are not so bad that they ought to be deleted.

(Unless you happen to feel inspiration strike and chose to use the edit button instead of course).

I have a [SE meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145287/is-recommend-deletion-secretly-a-vote-to-delete) proposing a better text than "looks good" for the "don't delete" button, such that it doesn't look like you have to actively approve of the post in order to vote against deletion, but so far the SE overlords have not proved receptive.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what you see with the Low Quality Post review screen? For me (because either I am a mod or because I have 20+ rep) it shows (after I click the "(more)" link to expand the options)

[image]

Given that it does not look good, that you cannot edit it, but you don't feel like it should be closed, perhaps the only sensible thing to do is to comment on the post (explaining why you feel that the post is low quality) and click "Skip".

Comment: Your screenshot is for a low quality answer. There I get the option "Recommend deletion" instead of your "Delete". For a low quality question I get "Recommend closing" (or something like that) I can't check at the moment, because I have no low quality question there. In contrast du low quality answer there is no option to recommend closing without any comment or with a customary comment, if I recall correctly.